# "Относительный" порядок наложения элементов z-index

Tags: css3, html, css

Надеюсь, что смогу понятно сформулировать. Пусть есть непустая HTML страничка с набором блоков. У некоторых из них с помощью CSS задано свойство z-index. И имеется блок div.parent в котором лежат div.line и div.img. Требуется поставить div.parent на самый верх, среди всех элементов, а внутри него поставить div.line и поверх неё div.img. Возможно ли сделать средствами CSS так, чтобы z-index у div.line и div.img был меньше чем у остальных элементов, то есть как бы отсчет шел относительно div.parent.

Спрашивайте, если не понятно, поясню.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если я правильно понял тебя то тебе надо установить `z-index:1` для того блока который должен  быть впереди всех и `z-index:2` для блока который должен быть за ним

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 3
}
.line {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 2
}
.img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: position: relative; нужно добавить к каждому элементу иначе z-index не сработает